# PerformClick analogue for UWP

Tags: button, uwp, click

I am writing a helper for Gamepad, so I need to call all click handlers that may be assigned to a button (if any) under focus.

Something like that:

```
(FocusManager.GetFocusedElement() as ButtonBase)?.PerformClick();
```

Method `PerformClick` is supported by WinForms, but I can't find an analogue for UWP. Is there any?  Or maybe there is a way to get a set of  Click event handlers assigned to a ButtonBase and Invoke them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the `Click` like this -

```
var ap = new ButtonAutomationPeer(YourButtonReference);
var ip = ap.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider;
ip?.Invoke();
```

Comment: Works! Thank you. It would be more convenient (and more natural), if Button Reference could be ButtonBase rather than Button, given that Click event is actually defined in ButtonBase. My buttons are all user controls deriving from ButtonBase.

Comment: @cyanide yeah unfortunately the other one is protected.

Comment: Yeah, I've already noticed. There is a constructor ButtonBaseAnimationPeer(ButtonBase), but it is protected. BTW, not the only UWP case when a useful constructor is protected or not exposed.  WPF gives much more freedom.

Comment: Tried to overcome protection by using a wrapper: class AccessibleButtonBaseAutomationPeer : ButtonBaseAutomationPeer {public AccessibleButtonBaseAutomationPeer(ButtonBase owner) : base(owner) { } }. Compiles all right, but GetPattern returns null !

Answer (score 0):

Following **Justin XL**'s answer (1 line):

```
(new ButtonAutomationPeer(button).GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider).Invoke();
```

or:

```
((IInvokeProvider)new ButtonAutomationPeer(button).GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke)).Invoke();
```